# Do I need CSRF-protection without users or login?

Tags: django, security, csrf

I am building a Django application where people can register for events. Everyone can register, there's no user account or login, i.e. no authentication. Verification is done through an an email with a link that has to be clicked in order to activate the registration.
I'm unsure whether I need to enable CSRF-protection for these forms. It boils down to the following question:
Is CSRF-protection necessary for every POST-request (which doesn't leave the domain) or only for POST-requests by logged-in users?

What could be done with a CSRF-attack? I know you can use it to circumvent the same origin policy and post whatever you want in the name of the user, but can you also use it to alter a real post by the user or steal their data? If a malicious site could learn the data the user posted or silently alter their request that would be a reason for me to use it. If it just means that another website can create additional registrations then no, because so can everyone else.
(I know that it doesn't cost much to just use it everywhere and I might in fact do that, but I'm trying to understand the principle better)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to the other answer, CSRF fundamentally is not about sending cookies. CSRF is about another website being able to have a user visiting it send a request to your application. If there is a session, it needs to be via something like cookies for this to be successful, because cookies for example will be sent automatically. But there are other forms of authentication that will be sent automatically, for example client certificates.

Also if there is no authentication, even easier, requests can be made. And that sounds like a problem in your case too.

What another website can do is if a user visit them, they can have *that user* perform actions in *your application*. For example they can have them register for an event, without them even noticing it. Or the malicious website can deregister people from events if that's possible. They can do whatever *in the name of the victim user* that is possible on your website, without the victim knowing about it, just by having them visiting the malicious website.

So to put it another way, the probelm is not that another website can perform actions in your application - they could do it with CSRF enabled too if there is no authentication. But without CSRF protection, they can have **your users** perform actions inadvertently **in your application**, just by having them visit the malicious website.

Only you can tell, whether this is a problem in your case. Without more info, I think you should have CSRF protection enabled.

Comment: Thank you, the part about the other website being able to perform user actions *covertly* was what I was looking for!

Comment: The distinction between "the attacker is doing things" and "the attacker is making the user do things" only makes sense of there is authentication, right? Without it there is just "someone is doing things".

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean by "have that user perform actions in your application". Is this about JavaScript? In that case there is still the Same Origin Policy, or am I missing something?

Comment: The SOP is about getting the response (in javascript), but not about sending the request. The request will be sent, the server will receive and process it, potentially changing state, leading to CSRF. Let's say you have a simple anonymous vote counter. You want to count visitors' votes for candidates, without login, but with independent mechanisms to stop duplicates (like every IP votes once). Without csrf protection, another site can gather votes for their selected candidates. The SOP doesn't help, there are no users, and this is technically CSRF. Therefore, I don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: But is it "technically CSRF"? [OWASP says](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf): "Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) is an attack that forces an end user to execute unwanted actions on a web application in which they’re **currently authenticated**." Of course, you could define it to include anonymous requests, but that doesn't seem very useful to me. In your scenario, for example, CSRF mitigations would not be effective at protecting the application, since there are plenty of other ways to generate anonymous requests from different IP addresses.

Comment: I kind of see your point, but CSRF protection would indeed protect the app from a malicious site that uses its visitors to vote (when those users did not intend to vote at all, and potentially will never know they did). Circumventing the independent restrictions (like IP address check) is a different topic, I still think this would count as csrf, supported by the fact that the protection against csrf does prevent this attack. But anyway, I don't want to argue about definitions, all I wanted to say was that csrf protection can make sense without auth sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

CSRF attacks rely on the fact that the browser will send the information that you gave it to identify your users (cookies, typically) along with requests to your site, even ones triggered by a third party (like a malicious script).

If you don't have users, and aren't sending any such information to the browser, your application isn't in danger from CSRF.